# Latex Beamer Block: Increase border width

Tags: beamer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have framed blocks in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11211/can-i-have-framed-blocks-in-beamer)

Is it possible to increase the border width of a block?
I have identified the following section of code as being responsible for the block layout:

```
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{ 
 \vskip.75ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,shadow=true,leftskip=1.5cm,colsep*=.75ex]{block title}%
        \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
      \usebeamerfont{block body}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,shadow=true,sep=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    %\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
      }
     \setbeamertemplate{block end}{
      \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

However, the only things I can seem to change is foreground and background color, and shadow. But what I want to do is make a strong, colored border around the whole block. Is this possible?

Comment: `beamercolorbox` does not have this option. The options for it are listed on pages `124-125` of the [beamer manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/beamer). To get boxes with frames you can use [`TikZ`](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgf) or [`mdframed`](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/mdframed).

Answer (score 2):

As an example, with `TikZ` you could create your own block environment to look something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\newsavebox\blockbox
\newenvironment{myblock}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\blockbox}%
    \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
}{
    \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}
  \tikz\node[
    fill=green!40!blue!20,
    draw=red!30,
    line width=10pt,
    inner sep=7.5pt,
    rounded corners,
    outer sep=0pt,
  ]{\usebox\blockbox};
}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{myblock}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{myblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: beamer block]

You could modify the code to supply arguments to the environment that are passed on to the `TikZ` node that is drawn.