# Redefine beamer's blocks

Tags: beamer, block

I'm trying to redefine beamer's blocks to obtain something like this (upper block) :
[image]

I've found 3 sites (with codes and pictures) which may help, but I'm unable to reach this goal on my own.

Here's the sites :

- [First](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120669/draw-custom-frame-around-text)
- [Second](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/)
- [Third](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11211/can-i-have-framed-blocks-in-beamer)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, we should follow three links in order to assemble a solution? ;-)

Comment: Please add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what you have tried so far and how close you have come to a solution (but don't add unnecessary code). This code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and it should compile. Doing this makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will:) As it is we have no idea what beamer styles etc you are using and so we'd have to waste a lot time starting from scratch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a `tcolorbox` based implementation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.15,0.15,0.53}

\makeatletter

\newtcbox{\titlebox}{
    enhanced,
    overlay={
        \draw[myblue,fill=myblue](frame.south east)--+(0,.2)to[bend right]+(.2,-0)--cycle;},
        colback=myblue,
        top=-1pt,bottom=-2pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,
        boxrule=1pt,
        colframe=myblue,
        sharp corners=south,
        colupper=white,
        fontupper=\bfseries
}

\newtcolorbox{myblock}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    left=2pt,
    right=2pt,
    colframe=myblue,
    boxrule=1pt,
    colback=blue!10,
    overlay={
        \def\myblock@tempa{#1}
        \ifx\myblock@tempa\@empty
        \else
        \draw[myblue,fill=myblue]($(frame.north west)+(.2pt,-.2pt)$)--+(.1,0)to[bend right]+(-0,-.1)--cycle;
        \node [
            anchor=south west,
            inner sep=0pt,
            outer sep=0pt
        ]at(frame.north west){\titlebox{#1}};
    \fi
    },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \begin{myblock}[Corollary]
      \textit{If $_{\chi PP}(M)=2$ a haplotype matrix M we can find an optimal pp-partition in polynomial time}
   \end{myblock}

   \begin{myblock}
      this block has no title
   \end{myblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The fancy stuff (rounded corners etc. is done with TikZ and is conditionally excluded if the box has no title.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tcolorbox inner theme as a starting point and start with your customisation from there:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 


\usecolortheme{orchid}
\useinnertheme[rounded]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\tcbsetforeverylayer{
    boxrule=1pt,
    borderline={1.5pt}{0pt}{beamer@tcb@titlebg},
    sharp corners=northwest,
    attach boxed title to top left={},
    boxed title style={
      bottom=-1mm,
      top=0mm,
      sharp corners=south,
      rounded corners=northwest,
      arc=1.3mm,
      overlay={
        \fill[beamer@tcb@titlebg] (frame.south east) -- ++(0,3mm) arc [start angle=180, end angle=270, radius=3mm] -- cycle; 
        \fill[beamer@tcb@titlebg] (frame.south west) -- ++(1.8mm,-0.5mm) arc [start angle=90, end angle=180, radius=1.3mm] -- cycle; 
      }   
    }, 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{title}
content...
\end{block}

\begin{Corollary}[test]
content...
\end{Corollary}

\begin{exampleblock}{title}
content...
\begin{alertblock}{title}
content...
\end{alertblock}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]