# How make framed blocks in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles

I want to create a block in every frame like this

[image]

Because I don't like to use classical blocks like this
[image]
Could you please give me the necessary code ? Thank you

Comment: You could try to use empty slides and tcolorbox. But without MWE and any attempt it will be hard to help you.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Do you a sample theme you wish to use?

Comment: I use the theme Madrid

Comment: Should "definition 1" be the frametitle? What should happen to the elements which are normally on a slide of the Madrid theme, e.g. head and footline?

Comment: it's not  the frametitle, it is only the title of a block

Comment: For something like this, you might want to have a look at ConTeXt presentations. There are some similar designs in context reference book. Provided you have some time to learn…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a similar box with the `tcolorbox` package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{pabox}[1]{%
    colback=white,
    colframe=structure.fg,
    colbacktitle=white!90!structure.fg,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    title=Definition~\thetcbcounter .,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm, xshift=0.5cm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{pabox}
This is my own box with a mandatory
numbered title and options.
\end{pabox}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hi! how can you add the name of the definition in the upper small box ? thank you :)

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337331/how-to-create-a-rounded-beamer-block-with-the-title-starting-a-bit-forward-than?noredirect=1&lq=1 
here i see that I can add a parameter in the options '  title=#2, '  but it erases the word theorem. How can I have theorem, the counter and the name of it into parenthesis?

Comment: @MarineGalantin Seems like I was too slow and Christian Hupfer already answered this.

Comment: but do you know how to define a specific counter ressetting at each chapter? I don't understand the answer of Christian and I can't make it work :/

Comment: @MarineGalantin Then it would be best if you take Christians answer and write a follow up question about your counter problem.