# tcolorbox use for theorems correction

Tags: tcolorbox, typography

so I didn't want to do a duplicate but apparently I can't know the answer on my previous post...

so the original question was here : [tcolorbox use for theorems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411879/tcolorbox-use-for-theorems)

and now I ve done this:

it solves my problems. Can I ask you how to modify one part of the code ?

So with this question :[How make framed blocks in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400957/how-make-framed-blocks-in-beamer/400987#400987)
I have create the box theoreme. But I d like to write the name of the theorem in the small upper box. How can I add this :)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{vert}{RGB}{0,181,0}
\definecolor{oran}{RGB}{223,74,0}
\definecolor{viol}{RGB}{134,0,175}
\definecolor{roug}{RGB}{215,15,0}



\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{theoreme}[1]{%
    colback=white,
    colframe=roug,
    colbacktitle=white!90!roug,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    title=Théorème~\thetcbcounter .,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm, xshift=0.5cm}
}





\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
        fontupper=\normalsize\itshape,
         top=0mm,
         bottom=0mm,
         right=0mm,
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=white,
        %coltitle=red,
        attach boxed title to top left,
        boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, bottom=1.5mm},
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        },
    SV/.style={thmbox, coltitle=vert,
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[vert][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[vert][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay first={
            \draw[vert][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[vert][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[vert][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[vert][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        },
    SO/.style={thmbox, coltitle=oran,
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[oran][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay first={
            \draw[oran][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        },   
    LQ/.style={thmbox, coltitle=viol,
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[viol][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
        overlay first={
            \draw[viol][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
    },  
}


\newtcbtheorem[]{ajoutationV}{Exemple}{thmbox,SV}{theo}
\newtcbtheorem[]{ajoutationO}{Exercice}{thmbox,SO}{theo}
\newtcbtheorem[]{demo}{Démonstration}{thmbox,LQ}{theo}


\begin{document}



\begin{ajoutationV}{}{}
\lipsum[2]
\end{ajoutationV}


\begin{ajoutationO}{}{}
\lipsum[2]
\end{ajoutationO}


\begin{demo}{}{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{demo}



\begin{theoreme}
WOW

\end{theoreme}




\end{document}
```

I have another problem. I want to define a counter but I don't know how to reset it at the end of each chapter. Any idea?

Comment: A side note: It looks like that, for some reason, your `theoreme` environment is eating the first character inside it...

Comment: yes... I don't know why :/

Comment: Your other problem is totally unrelated to this question (please do not ask for multiple issues in one post!), but `\newcounter{foo}[chapter]` defines a counter named `foo` in your document. However, your document above uses the `article` class which does not provide chapters

Comment: yes? :) I ve seen it but the aim is writting this code in a book where chapter are defined...  you are saying that \newcounter{foo}[chapter] would work in a book?

Answer (score 3):

The name of the theorem is written in the small attached box already, but the `tcolorbox` `theoreme` is defined with one mandatory argument, so it expects one argument -- if this is not given, it will gobble the first token inside of the environment, `WOW` becomes `OW` then.

I suggest to write

`\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{theoreme}[2][]{%`

instead, in this case the first argument is optional and can be used to change the options of the box. If it is omitted, no harm is done, the second argument is mandatory and meant for the title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{vert}{RGB}{0,181,0}
\definecolor{oran}{RGB}{223,74,0}
\definecolor{viol}{RGB}{134,0,175}
\definecolor{roug}{RGB}{215,15,0}



\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{theoreme}[2][]{%
    colback=white,
    colframe=roug,
    colbacktitle=white!90!roug,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    title=Théorème~\thetcbcounter.\ #2,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm, xshift=0.5cm},%
    #1% For possible options
}





\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
        fontupper=\normalsize\itshape,
         top=0mm,
         bottom=0mm,
         right=0mm,
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=white,
        %coltitle=red,
        attach boxed title to top left,
        boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, bottom=1.5mm},
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        },
    SV/.style={thmbox, coltitle=vert,
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[vert][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[vert][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay first={
            \draw[vert][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[vert][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[vert][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[vert][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        },
    SO/.style={thmbox, coltitle=oran,
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[oran][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay first={
            \draw[oran][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        },   
    LQ/.style={thmbox, coltitle=viol,
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[viol][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
        overlay first={
            \draw[viol][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
    },  
}


\newtcbtheorem[]{ajoutationV}{Exemple}{thmbox,SV}{theo}
\newtcbtheorem[]{ajoutationO}{Exercice}{thmbox,SO}{theo}
\newtcbtheorem[]{demo}{Démonstration}{thmbox,LQ}{theo}


\begin{document}



\begin{ajoutationV}{}{}
\lipsum[2]
\end{ajoutationV}


\begin{ajoutationO}{}{}
\lipsum[2]
\end{ajoutationO}


\begin{demo}{}{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{demo}



\begin{theoreme}{A nice theorem}
WOW
\end{theoreme}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: so by addind the [] you define a command where a title can be add? and what is the #1?

Comment: @MarineGalantin: No, `[]` is an optional argument which can be omitted, where `[2][]` would define one with a mandatory argument. You should really read some introduction to LaTeX. And do you want to add some extra title to `Theoreme~\thetcbcounter`? That is not obvious from your question

Comment: I read but this is not that obvious. I am not really into informatics, always get bad grades in this topic :p

I want that the title of the box would be:  Theorem {counter} (name_of_theorem)

( there was also the question of how to reset the counter...?)

Comment: @MarineGalantin: I added a comment about resetting the counter just below your question

Comment: @MarineGalantin: And LaTeX is not Quantum Field theory which is really difficult ;-) I've changed the answer

Comment: that's gorgeous, thank you ! so if instead of having this code wirtten on an article but in a book, how would you do to reset the counter?

Comment: @MarineGalantin: See my comment below you question, the one regarding `\newcounter` ...