# Environments with tcolorbox, referencing

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, environments, tcolorbox, theorems

I have a large textbook written and I wish to add color boxes around my theorems, lemmas, etc without changing my main text too much. Currently, each theorem environment is defined in the usual way, e.g.,

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{proposition*}{Proposition}
```

To add color boxes, I could of course use tcolorbox as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411968/tcolorbox-use-for-theorems-correction). My problem is that tcolorbox's theorems are defined like

```
\begin{theorem}{theorem name}{reference}
```

whereas my 1000-page textbook define theorems using

```
\begin{theorem}{theorem name}\label{reference}
```

So my question is:

*Is there any way of getting around this. I.e., redefining the theorem-environment so that I would still be able to reference theorems using the usual \label{reference}?*

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Which editor are you using? If you use an editor capable to search and replace with regex, I would go this route. Hacks on a 1000-page document are not recommended, although Ignassi's solution will work, I would rather fix the manuscript. I use Sublime 3

Comment: I would prefer to keep the main text as it is. (My coauthor does not like this boxed theorem format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you accept to rename your theorems to something different, you can use `tcolorboxenvironment` to change theorems aspect and keep previous labeling mechanism.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{proposition*}{Proposition}

\newenvironment{mytheorem}{\begin{theorem}}{\end{theorem}}

\tcolorboxenvironment{mytheorem}{colback=blue!30, colframe=blue!70!black}

\begin{document}

\section{One}

\begin{mytheorem}{One theorem}\label{OneTheorem}
some words
\end{mytheorem}

Reference to theorem~\ref{OneTheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: muzimuzhi's simpler solution**

it seems that any previous existing environment can be `tcbcolorized`, we don't need to rename it as I did in original answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{proposition*}{Proposition}

%\newenvironment{mytheorem}{\begin{theorem}}{\end{theorem}}

\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{colback=blue!30, colframe=blue!70!black}

\begin{document}

\section{One}

\begin{theorem}{One theorem}\label{OneTheorem}
some words
\end{theorem}

Reference to theorem~\ref{OneTheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input! It would be ideal if I could keep the main text intact and keep the format "\begin{theorem}\label{}". Is there any chance of making this work?

Comment: @wnx I'm sorry but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway for taking the time to think about it - I appreciate it!

Comment: @wnx In any case you can try to make a new question showing my proposal and asking how to avoid changing the names.

Comment: Seems to be just `\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{colback=blue!30, colframe=blue!70!black}`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you. I thought that an auxiliar environment was needed.

Comment: @wnx Please take a look at updated answer. It's easier. You don't have to change anything in your text.

Comment: Thank you very much!