# Blocks in CambridgeUS beamer

Tags: beamer

Can I get coloured highlight all around the block? (currently its just highlighted/shadowed only around the bottom edge and the right edge)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}   
\usecolortheme{default} 
\usefonttheme{default}  
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\title[Your Short Title]{Your Presentation}
\author{AA}
\institute{SS}
\date{Date of Presentation}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame} 
bLAH bLAH
\pause
\\
\begin{block}{}
BLAH
\end{block} 

\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Those who would love to help you will welcome your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Any code you could provide is a great starting point for them.

Comment: I have now added a MWE

Comment: So you want the highlight around the box to be colored, but the background of the box itself to remain white?

Comment: Yes - at least get the highlight to be all around the box rather than just at the bottom and right!

Comment: If you want framed blocks, have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11481/36296

Comment: As the answers there show, it will be easier to use tcolorboxes than to hack `beamer`'s `block` environment. Note that it isn't entirely clear what you want. Drop shadows are inherently directional. So probably you do want a frame like that in the link samcarter pointed to? In that case, look at the answer there using `tcolorbox`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `tcolorbox` solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS} 

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}  

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame} 
        \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colframe=white,colback=white, fuzzy halo = 1mm with gray] 
        Preface 
    \end{tcolorbox} 
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The code can be further simplified with the new tcolorbox inner theme (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-tcolorbox )

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS} 

\useinnertheme[shadow=false]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{fuzzy halo=1mm with gray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame} 
        \begin{block}{Title}
        Preface 
    \end{block} 
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]